# How to create links between points and nearest vertex of polyline feature class?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, polyline-creation

I have a point feature class and for each point I want to find the nearest vertex on a polyline feature class. I then want to create a line between each point and it's nearest vertex on the other layer.

How is this done?

If it can't be done with a polyline layer, I can also use a point layer in lieu.

Comment: This can easily be done in python if you are comfortable with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert your line vertices to points using [Feature Vertices To Points](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//00170000003p000000).  Then using the [Near tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en%20/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001q000000), you can find the nearest vertex for each point.  As for creating new polylines from these points, use the tool: XY to line.

Comment: there are also 2 tools to create lines XY to line(management) and Point to line(managementà

Comment: The solution required first conducting a Near Analysis. In that, "location" was checked to create XY coordinates for the nearest locations on the network. I also calculated the XY coordinates of all the points in my original point layer. Then I used XY to line and specified the start and end XY coordinates. This gave me a new feature class of lines. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above, you can use python to easily accomplish this task, or if you are not comfortable with that, you can do a NEAR analysis - which will find the nearest point on a line to each point in your dataset.  Unfortunatly, this nearest point will not necesarily be a vertex on the line.  In order to do this, you could convert the line to point features first - using the FeatureVerticiestoPoints tool, then do the near - this will give you a list of nearest points - which you can extract the X,Y coorindates for, and then build your line from that.  Hopefully this all makes sense.